# Dividing by larger number first

Tags: java

```
    System.out.print("Enter the numbers here: ");
    Scanner gc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int firstNumber = gc.nextInt();
    int SecondNumber = gc.nextInt();
```

So that is the main part of my code. How could I divide the larger number by the smaller one easily, example if I put 1 for firstNumber and 2 for secondNumber how could I make it divide secondNumber by firstNumber.

Comment: Use an if statement comparing the two numbers, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.print("Enter the numbers here: ");
Scanner gc = new Scanner(System.in);
int firstNumber = gc.nextInt();
int SecondNumber = gc.nextInt();
if(firstNumber>SecondNumber)
{
   firstNumber/SecondNumber;
}
else
   SecondNumber/firstNumber;
```

Comment: Thank you, any idea how I could do it with 3 numbers? Or would I just do it for every combination.

Comment: Oh you can just use a for loop to compare but 3 numbers? How are you going to divide them? Or do you just want the smallest number